# Starts with Salesforce app in Android

Tags: android, salesforce

I am very much confused about the native application creation in Android.Can anyone give me the way to create a sample application in Salesforce. I have android application development requirements(Java,Eclipse,Android-sdk..). What are the requirements needed to develop Salesforce native application in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce provides mobile packs and SDKs to create native applications.

There is a [Salesforce Android SDK in github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) and instructions in [the mobile pack site](http://www2.developerforce.com/mobile/getting-started/android)

Answer (score 0):

Use Salesforce Touch Platform. It is Salesforce Mobile SDK + Support for Authentication/Identity Management.

Salesforce Touch is the Only choice you have.